# SharePoint file size is different than source file after uploading

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

We are developing a WinForms (desktop) application in .Net framework 4.5.2 with C# language.

Using Microsoft.Graph library 1.21.0 and Micorosft.Graph.Core 1.19.0 version to copy files from windows local machine to SharePoint/OneDrive cloud storage.

I tried with Microsoft.Graph library 3.18.0 and Micorosft.Graph.Core 1.22.0 and .Net 4.6.2 framework but same issue.

1. We are copy files less than 4 MB using following method

> uploadedItem = await
> MainDrive.Root.ItemWithPath(Uri.EscapeDataString(targetFilePath)).Content.Request().PutAsync(stream,
> cancellationToken);

2. Files larger than 4 MB are being copied using ChunkUpload

> ```
> var session = await MainDrive.Root.ItemWithPath(targetFilePath).CreateUploadSession().Request().PostAsync(cancellationToken);
> var provider = new ChunkedUploadProvider(session, graphClient, stream, OneDriveChunkSize);
>
> var chunkRequests = provider.GetUploadChunkRequests();  
>
> var trackedExceptions = new List<Exception>();
>
> foreach (UploadChunkRequest request in chunkRequests)
> {
>    await CheckforBandwidthThrotelling(fileInfo.Name, fp, cancellationToken);
>    UploadChunkResult result = await provider.GetChunkRequestResponseAsync(request, trackedExceptions);
>    if (result.UploadSucceeded)
>    {
>     uploadedItem = result.ItemResponse;
>    }
> }
> ```

Issue: We are getting the file size larger than source after copying files to SharePoint. It works well in case of OneDrive personal using same api's and method.
I found that it's due to Metadata get added to file. We are not maintaining any multiple version of files on SharePoint.
This issue is mostly with office files (docs, xlsx and ppt) but not with txt files of any size.

The application differentiate the files mismatch on source and destination based upon timestamp and file size. As file found different size in next run, it copies the file again.

The same issue is reported on [github](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/935)

[Some more description about issue](https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/11/sharepoint-changes-files-as-they-are.html)

I am looking for a workaround to compare file size between source and destination to decide whether file need to copy again.

Comment: _The same issue is reported on github_ - so what is your question?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with this API, but is there a way to store metadata of your own, outside of the file (e.g. in a library column or other metadata field)? If so, you could store a hash of the original file and use that to check whether the file changed.

Comment: @JLRishe I also tried to found a way to store metadata but there is not direct way. Also it supports file versioning so metadata may different to each version of file.

Comment: quick question - Outside of your application, can you repro the issue with MS Graph Explorer or POSTMAN as well?

Comment: @Dev yes you can reproduce the same by drag/drop file in SharePoint portal too.

Comment: I'm experiencing same problem, and it appears that the problem is with SharePoint. Several times a week I need to transfer large number of files (mostly .xlsx) from a win server to my local SharePoint folder. Then those files are synced with SharePoint online. The moment after a file is synced, it is downloaded with a different size, same content. This makes the the sync software (FreeFileSync) that I use to transfer files from the server useless. I had to use OneDrive for Bussiness or OneDrive Personal instead, as with them the I don't have a problem. It is a shame that MS does that!